# Derived class calls parent's method

Tags: c++, cgal

(*Note:* The corresponding gist is available [here](https://gist.github.com/nschloe/640e280f5e54f12266f1b5ef9aca95ee).)

---

I have a number of methods which are derived from `std::unary_function<K::Point_3, K::FT>` plus `typedef K::Point_3 Point;` (the underlying library CGAL requires it) – The class is called `Function`.

I now need to add a number of instances of derived classes (example: `MySphere`) to a `Function_vector`:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Implicit_to_labeling_function_wrapper.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::FT FT;

class Function: public std::unary_function<K::Point_3, K::FT>
{
public:
  typedef K::Point_3 Point; // necessary
  // I'd rather not define operator() here
  virtual K::FT operator()(K::Point_3 p) const {return 0.0;}
};

class MySphere: public Function
{
public:
  virtual K::FT operator()(K::Point_3 p) const {return 3.14;}
};

typedef CGAL::Implicit_multi_domain_to_labeling_function_wrapper<Function>
                                               Function_wrapper;
typedef Function_wrapper::Function_vector Function_vector;

int main()
{
  MySphere f1;

  Function_vector v;
  v.push_back(f1);

  std::cout << f1(CGAL::ORIGIN) << std::endl; // MySphere::operator()
  std::cout << v[0](CGAL::ORIGIN) << std::endl; // Function::operator() :(

  return 0;
}
```

Problem:

`Function_vector` does not accept pointers, so the actually abstract `Function` class cannot be virtual and needs to implement `operator()` from `std::unary_function`. When adding a `MySphere` instance to the `Function_vector`, `MySphere` gets cast into `Function` and `Function`'s `operator()` is called, not `MySphere`'s.

How to have `v[0]` call `MySphere::operator()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, one can create another wrapper `MyFun` and feed it into `Function` à la

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Implicit_to_labeling_function_wrapper.h>

#include <memory>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::FT FT;

class MyFun: public std::unary_function<K::Point_3, K::FT>
{
  public:
  virtual K::FT operator()(K::Point_3 p) const = 0;
};

class MySphere: public MyFun
{
public:
  virtual K::FT operator()(K::Point_3 p) const {return 3.14;}
};

class Function: public std::unary_function<K::Point_3, K::FT>
{
  public:
  typedef K::Point_3 Point;

  explicit Function(std::shared_ptr<MyFun> fun):
    fun_(fun)
  {
  }

  virtual K::FT operator()(K::Point_3 p) const {
    return fun_->operator()(p);
  }

  private:
  std::shared_ptr<MyFun> fun_;
};


typedef CGAL::Implicit_multi_domain_to_labeling_function_wrapper<Function> Function_wrapper;
typedef Function_wrapper::Function_vector Function_vector;

int main()
{
  auto f1 = std::make_shared<MySphere>();

  Function_vector v;
  v.push_back(Function(f1));

  std::cout << (*f1)(CGAL::ORIGIN) << std::endl;
  std::cout << v[0](CGAL::ORIGIN) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you put a `Function` object into the vector, and therefore have [*object slicing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), you simply can't. Virtual function *needs* pointers or references to properly work with an inheritance tree.

The only advice I can give is that you rethink your design.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I'll get back to the CGAL devs.